# Serial communication between linux and 8051 microcontroller board using rs-232 in c

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, microcontroller, embedded-linux

I have problem in sending data serially using RS-232 from linux OS to uc 8051.
8051 setting:

baudrate = 9600;
comport = port1.
parity = none
stop bit = one

```
// my code for receiving data on 8051 uc
#include <reg51.h>

unsigned char value;
int i,j;

void ini()     
{
    TMOD=0x20;  //Timer1, mode 2, baud rate 9600 bps
    TH1=0XFD; 
    SCON=0x50;
    TR1=1;
}

void delay()
{
    for(i=0;i<=1000;i++)
    for (j=0;j<=300;j++);
}

void recieve() 
{
    unsigned char value;
    while(RI==0);
    value=SBUF;
    P1=value;
    RI=0;
}

void main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        ini();
        recieve();
    }
}

// and code which run on linux is as following
#include <stdio.h> // standard input / output functions
#include <string.h> // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h> // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h> // File control definitions
#include <errno.h> // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h> // POSIX terminal control definitionss
#include <time.h>   // time calls

int open_port(void)
{
    int fd; // file description for the serial port

    fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if (fd == -1) // if open is unsucessful
    {
        //perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
        printf("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
        printf("port is open.\n");
    }

    return(fd);
} //open_port

int configure_port(int fd)      // configure the port
{
    struct termios port_settings;      // structure to store the port settings in

    cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B9600);    // set baud rates
    cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B9600);

    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;    // set no parity, stop bits, data bits
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings);    // apply the settings to the port
    return(fd);

} //configure_port

int query_modem(int fd)   // query modem with an AT command
{
    char n;
    fd_set rdfs;
    struct timeval timeout;

    // initialise the timeout structure
    timeout.tv_sec = 10; // ten second timeout
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    // Create byte array
    unsigned char send_bytes[] = {  0x00, 0xff};

    write(fd, send_bytes, 2);  //Send data
    printf("Wrote the bytes. \n");

    // do the select
    n = select(fd + 1, &rdfs, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    // check if an error has occured
    if(n < 0)
    {
        perror("select failed\n");
    }
    else if (n == 0)
    {
        puts("Timeout!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nBytes detected on the port!\n");
    }
    return 0;
} //query_modem

int main(void)
{ 
    int fd = open_port();
    configure_port(fd);
    query_modem(fd);
    return(0);
} // main
```

But I have problem .. so plz help me out and tell me in which format linux sends data through rs-232. Also receiving format of 8051 micro-controller.
Need sample code in C.

Comment: We need your code and the errors you are getting

Comment: sir i have posted my code....

Comment: what happens if you run this? This is a pretty specific question so you probably should include as much info as you can about what's happening in the hopes that someone has done something similar.

Comment: change the 8051 code to constantly transmit the 0x55 character, in 8n1 mode that is a square wave.  Look at this on a scope and verify the clock rate is correct.  On the host side take a paperclip and short sockets 2 and 3 and verify what you send out you get back.  Once all that is done and correct you should at least have one way communications with which you can print register contents, etc and debug your way through reception of characters on the 8051.

Answer (score 0):

I recomment basic fault finding

- make sure you use correct cables (2 & 3 crossed out, no handshake lines to start with)
- seperate the devices, i.e. connect your Linux machine to a PC running a terminal
  program and try to establish 2-way communication - work on the Linux / C code until you achieve
- connect your 8051 to a PC running a terminal program ....
- connect Linux and 8051 only if they both work against a known and proven device

If your 8051 code sample represents all code .... how would the 8051 respond to the AT .... it can only receive.

good luck